# HTTPS и Ajax из JS

Tags: ajax, https, javascript

Проблема в следующем - На страничке с https протоколом должен быть ajax который подгружает данные с сервера, но весь трабл в том что responceText возвращается равный пустой строке. Может кто-то с таким сталкивался? Как (и можно ли вообще) пользоваться ajax с протоколом https

Answer (score 1):

Ajax с https работает прекрасно. А пустая строка - значит так отдает обработчик. Проблема наверняка в нем. Через firebug посмотрите что передается запросом.